# When changing the time on a remote server with PS (after turning off auto time sync), it keeps switching back to current time

Tags: remote-access, powershell-remoting

Summary:
I have 4 systems running Windows Server 2022. One system has the PS code and the other 3 are targets to run this code on via PS "Invoke-Command". The objective is to turn off the automatic time sync option on the remote system, then setting the date to the current date + 1 day. Then checking again on the date on those servers.

First, the script collects the list of servers:

```
$servers = Get-content -Path .\testservers.txt
```

Then, turns off the time sync option (via the only way I found: registry)

```
foreach ($server in $servers){
    Write-host "Turning off time sync on $server -  " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $scriptBlock = {
        $props = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters\"
        if ($props.Type -ne "NoSync"){
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters" -Name Type -Value "NoSync"
        }
    }
    $result = Invoke-command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
    Write-Host "$result"
}
```

Then, I set the date

```
foreach ($server in $servers){
    Write-host "Adding 1 day on $server -  " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $scriptBlock = {         Set-Date -Date ($Using:currentDateTime).AddDays(1) }
    $result = Invoke-command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
    Write-Host "$result"
}
```

Then after the date change, I recheck the date

```
foreach ($server in $servers){
    Write-host "Date on server $server -  " -NoNewline
    $result = Invoke-command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { Get-Date }
    Write-Host "$result"
}
```

I often see at least one of them switched back by this point. If I do another loop to check the dates perhaps 30 seconds later, they've all reverted back to current date.

(Yes, I know the code can be more streamlined.)

Any ideas? Could this be a matter of the registry change or the time change being done in a PS session and only living within that session?

Comment: Also, if I RDP to one of the target servers after running through these steps, the time synch setting is indeed turned off.

Comment: I tried switching my loops to using PSSessions instead and even with the sessions still "open", the dates eventually switched back.

Comment: Recalled that these systems are Hyper-V VMs. For each system, I went to the VM Settings, Integration Services and cleared the Time Synchronization option check box.  Still no dice.